# Unique lattice constant using X-ray diffraction

Tags: crystals, x-ray-crystallography, braggs-law

I recently learned about X-diffraction methods to analyse crystal lattices. One important law in this is the Bragg condition

$$\lambda = 2d\sin(\theta).$$

I understand that $d$ is the distance between the Atom layers in the crystal where the light wave gets "reflected". For cubic crystals, I have read that

$$d = \frac{a}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2+l^2}}$$

where $a$ is the lattice constant. So according to this, for an unknown crystal, knowing the orientation {hkl}, a bragg angle and the wavelength would give you the ability to determine a value for $a$.

But now I read that this does not give me a unique lattice constant, and that measurements of more orientations are required. But I do not understand how this would help. I tried drawing pictures of NaCl crystals in (100) and (110) to understand where this uncertainty comes from.

My suspicion is that we do not know on which (hkl) layers the light is reflected, so we could measure reflections from (100) or (200) etc, but I fail to see how measuring the same crystal in a different orientation would help me pin down a value for $a$. I tried to make drawings but it just confuses me, especially when I tried cubic crystals more complicated than NaCl.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Where and what have you read?